# How can i find the size of a intger/char in bytes using php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way I get the size of a PHP variable in bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085895/is-there-a-way-i-get-the-size-of-a-php-variable-in-bytes)

I need to find the size in bytes using php for int/char or an array . I think its possible with memory management in php .

Comment: IIRC, php does not use integer types, but uses floating point for everything.

Comment: @Wug: No, PHP has separate Int and Float types. Other types (Real, for instance) are pseudonyms for Float.

Comment: must be a different language then.  what am I thinking of... edit: I think its javascript.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192657/how-to-determine-the-memory-footprint-size-of-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

```
/* load before whit a value */
$before = memory_get_usage(FALSE);

/* make sure $temp dosn't have a content before */
$temp = NULL;

/* calculate current usage */
$before = memory_get_usage(FALSE);

/* copy the content to a nex varibale */
$temp = $variable_to_test . '';

/* calculate the new usage */
$after = memory_get_usage(FALSE);

/* clean up data */
unset($temp);

/* calculate the incresed memory usage */
$memory_usage = $after - $before;
```

Comment: did you try it? Because it won't work!

Comment: if i put a $temp = str_repeat() it counts correct, but if i just copies that its get a negative value? optimizen in php? or why?

Comment: `$temp = $variable_to_test` is called shallow copying, it won't actually take a place in the memory before you modify `$temp`. You can take one of two approaches: 1- `$temp = $variable_to_test;$temp .= '';` 2- `$temp = unserialize(serialize($variable_to_test))`

Comment: ok, thanks for explaining that, addad a concatination whit an empty string to the code above, and now it gets higher (probely correct) values