# PHP HTML Tidy: size limit to buffer

Tags: php, htmltidy

I'm trying to use the HTML Tidy implementation that's part of PHP (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) in order to reformat a large chunk of HTML.  I'm having a problem wherein Tidy is truncating the output past a certain point (about 8K).

When I create a string that's about 10K long & hand it to tidy_repair_string, like so:

```
$output = tidy_repair_string($output, array( 
    'indent' => true, // enforce indentation 
    'hide-comments' => true, // Remove the comments 
    'wrap' => 100, // Break each line after 100 chars 
    'output-html' => true, // Output as HTML 
    'char-encoding' => $encoding // The input/output encoding 
), $encoding);
```

I lops off everything after 8,070 characters.  If I pad the beginning of the string with, say, 10 characters then exactly 10 characters are left off the end.
**Is there a way to change the buffer size for tidy_repair_string, so that it's bigger?**

Looking at http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.getconfig.php there doesn't appear to be a config option for it, Google is remarkably unhelpful/my Google-fu has failed me, and there's not a ton of documentation around this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I'm using xampp-portable-lite-win32-1.8.1-VC9 on Windows 7.  The problem continues to happen even when I change php.ini to use memory_limit = 900M

Comment: may be save into file and parse file, not string?

Answer (score 1):

All right, I can think of a couple reasons why this could possibly be failing.

1. You've exceeded your memory limit with not just this function call, but loading the variable into memory and any pre-processing you're doing. To test this out, you could try increasing your memory limit in php.ini to something ungodly high, or you could use memory_get_usage().
   Run it once before creating your object, then again after creating your object, and take the difference between the two results. ([How to find memory used by an object in PHP? (sizeof)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075419/how-to-find-memory-used-by-an-object-in-php-sizeof))
2. PHP tidy is bootstrapping on a version of Linux's tidy program. I know that a while back, the program had a limit of 4096 characters put into it at once (http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/129973-tidy-4096-char-limit/), but it looks as though that error has been fixed. What I'd recommend just to test that theory though is to echo out your 10K string (it'll take a minute) and then run that straight through bash's tidy program. I decided to test this theory myself:

   From BASH, `echo $(python -c 'print 20000*"a"') > test_file`. Since a char is 1 byte, this command should create a file for us that is 20K. Obviously, this won't validate with tidy, but it's some nice junk text that I can throw at the program. Now feed it into tidy (If you don't have tidy on the command line, `sudo apt-get install tidy`) with `tidy < test_file`. For me, this doesn't fail, but maybe give it a try. If it doesn't fail, then it isn't specific to the bootstrapped bash tidy program.

   *Now we've eliminated php.ini and the actual bash tidy program as the problems.
3. I then tried to recreate your error.

   I started out using the comment from above, parsing a file rather than a string.

   ```
   <?PHP
   $output = tidy_repair_file("test_file");

   print strlen($output);
   ?>
   ```

   For the tidy_repair_file strlen, I got 20111 (where the additional 111 characters come from tidy formatting. No truncation.
   Then I tried to read it into active memory and parse it as a string.

   ```
   <?PHP
   $data = readfile("test_file"); //read a 20K file into active memeory

   $encoding = "ascii"; //I just set my encoding to 'ascii' because I like it...

   $output = tidy_repair_string($data, array(
   'indent' => true, // enforce indentation
   'hide-comments' => true, // Remove the comments
   'wrap' => 100, // Break each line after 100 chars
   'output-html' => true, // Output as HTML
   'char-encoding' => $encoding // The input/output encoding
   ), $encoding);

   print strlen($output);
   ?>
   ```

I obviously am doing something wrong here, because I get my junk file echoed back to me, then '132', which is a basic HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    20001
  </body>
</html>
```

While I'm doing something wrong, this output does tell me that I am parsing a 20K file without truncation.

It's also worthwhile to note that I tried this code both using `php test.php` from the prompt and running it through a web browser. I get the same results. No truncation. It's also noteworthy for me to disclose that I'm running this out of Ubuntu Server, not Windows IIS.

Try outputting your variable to a file and then run tidy_repair_file() against it. Obviously, this solution is not sustainable and won't scale, but it will inform you of whether or not it's a problem with the original string.

Also, try running strlen() on $output before and after your tidy call - make sure that your string is a 10K string before it ever hits tidy...just as a sanity check.

Good luck, and I hope some of this helps!

Comment: Wow!  Thank you a ton for your thorough, thoughtful reply!  (I wish I had more upvotes :)  ).

The code I used to test the problem is at http://pastebin.com/fum84SpW. 

Step #1: I tried changing the memory limit to 900 MB, using memory_limit = 900M in php.ini.  It's still happening.
Step #2: I'm not sure how to run HTML tidy from the command line so that it uses the php_tidy.dll that php uses.
Step #3: Your post has reminded me that I probably ought to have specified the platform I'm using - XAMPP on Windows.  I'll go edit the original post to make that clear.